# How to make NCalc to compute using decimal type instead of double?

Tags: c#, forms, decimal, ncalc

I'm currently making a calculator using windows form and I'm using the string data type to store the math expression entered by the user. Except, when wanting to convert it to a data type which can give me the result I need to use an evaluator so I added the NCalc library to my project but it converts it to a double and I want it to give me a decimal as an output for precision reasons.

Is there any way to configure NCalc to perform computation in `decimal` instead of `double`? If not possible then what would be an efficient alternative?

```
    string expression = "2+4+36/12"
    double convertedExpression = Decimal.parse(expression);
```

It doesn't work this way but here is the idea of what I want. But it doesn't matter which way do I use to convert it I just want to convert a string wut==ith a mathematical expression to a decimal with the result of course.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

It looks like NCalc only supports parsing [int / double / string / datetime / bool] constants;
[Grammer/NCalc.g](https://github.com/MichaelAguilar/NCalc/blob/88b938dd03a3e9281ed42b42dce511faaff7b88d/Grammar/NCalc.g#L208)

You could define your own named function to do the conversion;

```cs
    var expr = new Expression("decimal(\"0.123\")");
    expr.EvaluateFunction += evaluateFunction;

    private void evaluateFunction(string name, FunctionArgs args){
        if (name == "decimal")
            arg.Result = decimal.Parse((string)args.Parameters[0].Evaluate());
        ...
    }
```

Comment: But even if I convert it to a decimal it's a double in the first place therefore I loose precision which I need because I want to make a calculator

Comment: Note that my example expression specified the value as a string constant. If you wanted to change the way numbers were parsed, you'd probably need to fork NCalc.

Comment: You might want to consider using the C# Roslyn compiler instead https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdndevs/2015/12/01/adding-c-scripting-to-your-development-arsenal-part-1/